# Android - Convert adroid.support.v4.app.FragmentManager to FragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I have some nested Fragments and I want to display a `Fragment` inside a `FragmentTabHost`.

In the `FragmentTabHost` `setup(...)` method, the second parameter should be a `FragmentManager` but I am targeting Android API 15 which doesn't have the `getChildFragmentManager()` method available so I have to use the support library.

I am getting an error saying that:

**'setup(android.content.Context, android.app.FragmentManager, int)' in 'android.support.v13.app.FragmentTabHost' cannot be applied to '(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity, android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, int)'**

In Android Studio:

[image: error message]

I want to use `getChildFragmentManager()` to avoid problems if things get even more nested in the future.

Does anyone knows how to overcome this?

---

EDIT:

My imports:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
```

Comment: As silly as it sounds I've fallen for the whole "wrong imports" before. Please check you haven't imported android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager when you imported FragmentManager, then the support fragment manager never gets used :)

Comment: I did import `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager `but I did not import `FragmentManager`

Comment: Wait a minute... what happens if you use android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost instead of the v13 one? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html#setup()

Comment: Well in this case the error disappears....but still, this will cover this case, since I guess I was lucky to have the v4 FragmentTabHost available...but what about a more general solution....is it possible to convert?

Comment: Now my `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add()` is getting an error, since the `add()` method needs a `Fragment` and I have a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` like: `add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())`

Comment: You've stated you need to use the support library for your project. You cannot use getFragmentManager(), you'll have to use getSupportFragmentManager() and your activity with the fragment in it has to extend FragmentActivity from the support library :)

Comment: Ok, it seems to compile! Now, I will just leave this question open in case someone knows a trick for a more broad problem, like the case where there isn't a support version available for something.

Comment: Glad that has solved your issue! To keep with stackoverflows rules I have to post an answer. Leave the question open for now as you said however :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
```

instead of the v13 one.
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html#setup()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html#setup%28%29)

Careful however, now that your application is using support fragments, ensure that you are using them in the future, such as using getSupportFragmentManager(); in your activities which now have to extend FragmentActivity and so forth.

Comment: If my class extends Fragment and i am using a FragmentPagerAdapter then what should i do?

Comment: Make sure your FragmentPagerAdapter uses android.support.v4.app.Fragment?